# How to fix Testflight "No Builds available" for some users

Tags: ios, testflight

I have a beta that has worked fine before. This is a build not a new app. I have the following in the testflight UI.  I have removed and re-added the testers group. I have removed and re-added the tester to the group. I have created another build completely. As you can see there are users that I could resend the invite to but two that are left hanging.

How can I fix this issue? Sadly, the main tester is one of the ones unavailable.

<s>I am going to try the public link but that does not track issues the same way.</s> The public link says the beta is not accepting testers.

Looking under builds from the testers tab:
[image]

[image]

---

The issue was the difference between what Apple considers 'internal' testers which are those who have an Apple developer account and those who do not. The latter must wait for Apple to review regardless. And they do it on Apple time. If you get it in less than 30 hours consider yourself blessed by the RNG gods ;) but you should plan for 48 hours to be safe with regard to test team schedules.

Comment: For those who still have this issue: I also faced this when I added a couple of new internal test users. The only way I could fix is adding builds before the users. Just remove users from the test, and then add build using build tab, then re-add users. then it will work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you forget to send build for review before beta as shown in the pictures?

> Only after review tester will be able to test app using the public link. Usually, it takes one day.

[image: Beta test]

**AND**

[image: Add build for review]

Comment: It has the build listed when I look. Adding pic to question.

Comment: I am thinking that I am still waiting for review. Although its been a day already.

Comment: So you need to wait when Apple will review your app, only after it tester will be able to test this build trough public link or trough invite(they will get mail about new build). How I said usually it takes one day sometimes longer.

Comment: Any up to date solution?

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 15, make sure that the build was sent as "TestFlight & App Store", as opposed to "TestFlight Internal Only". The latter does not allow external testing and it will show as "No Build Available".

[image]

Comment: save my time +1